# Yahoo finance xchange - taking the last update time

Tags: javascript, time, yahoo, yql

I'm doing a query on Yahoo finance xchange, but seems the time of update is not the most updated. Seems random, for each refresh, this value change, sometimes most updated, and sometimes less updated.

There is a way to always get the last time it was updated ?

Thank you.

```
        $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDUSD%22%2C%22USDEUR%22%2C%20%22USDJPY%22%2C%20%22USDCNY%22%2C%20%22USDGBP%22%2C%20%22USDBRL%22%2C%20%22EUREUR%22%20%2C%22EURUSD%22%2C%20%22EURJPY%22%2C%20%22EURCNY%22%2C%20%22EURGBP%22%2C%20%22EURBRL%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=", function (data) {
        var indices =   '<p style=\"border:1px solid #ccc; width:auto; padding:0 10px; background:#ddd;\"><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[0].Name + '</strong> ' + money(data.query.results.rate[0].Rate) + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[1].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[1].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[1].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[1].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[2].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[2].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[2].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[2].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[3].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[3].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[3].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[3].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[4].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[4].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[4].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[4].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[5].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[5].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[5].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[5].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p style=\"border:1px solid #ccc; width:auto; margin:20px 0 0; padding:0 10px; background:#ddd;\"><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[6].Name + '</strong> ' + money(data.query.results.rate[6].Rate) + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[8].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[8].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[8].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[8].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[7].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[7].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[7].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[7].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[9].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[9].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[9].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[9].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[10].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[10].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[10].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[10].Time + '</p>' +
                        '<p><strong>' + data.query.results.rate[11].Name + '</strong> (Fechamento ' + money(data.query.results.rate[11].Rate) + ') - ' + data.query.results.rate[11].Date + ' - ' + data.query.results.rate[11].Time + '</p>';
        $('#info').html(indices);
    });
    money = function (n) {
        var
            c = 4,
            d = ',',
            t = '.',
            s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
            i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
            j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
        return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
    };
```

Comment: what do you mean by time of update?  where is the update time that you want? in the response?

Comment: @ochi Yes, when I run my code, where is " data.query.results.rate [xx] .Time " he exchange for a update time that seems to be random and not the last . 
* sorry for my bad english.

Comment: and you want to sort by that time? or only get the most recent one? - your English is fine, no worries.  - BTW, do you know there is a version of SO in Portugues? (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @ochi I just want to get the most recent :P . and yes I know, but no one could answer me there, haha .

Comment: I am not what you want to do once you have the most recent time - let me know how to improve my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up constructing a date for each element in the array (map) and then filtering them to the oldest date (reduce)

what do you want to do with this date, I am not sure but here it is...

**UPDATED**

updated to return full JSON record containing the latest date/time stamp (instead of returning only the latest date)

```js
// sample response
var response = {"query":{"count":12,"created":"2016-04-29T20:13:39Z","lang":"en-us","results":{"rate":[{"id":"USDUSD","Name":"USD/USD","Rate":"1.0000","Date":"N/A","Time":"N/A","Ask":"1.0000","Bid":"1.0000"},   
{"id":"USDEUR","Name":"USD/EUR","Rate":"0.8775","Date":"4/29/2016",  "Time":"12:38pm","Ask":"0.8777","Bid":"0.8775"},{"id":"USDJPY","Name":"USD/JPY","Rate":"107.3910","Date":"4/29/2016","Time": "2:55pm","Ask":"107.3940","Bid":"107.3910"},{"id":"USDCNY","Name":"USD/CNY","Rate":"6.4868","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"12:49pm","Ask":"6.4878","Bid":"6.4868"},{"id":"USDGBP","Name":"USD/GBP","Rate":"0.6843","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"1:15pm","Ask":"0.6844","Bid":"0.6843"},{"id":"USDBRL","Name":"USD/BRL","Rate":"3.4492","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"3:33pm","Ask":"3.4496","Bid":"3.4492"},{"id":"EUREUR","Name":"EUR/EUR","Rate":"1.0000","Date":"1/29/2016","Time":"8:26am","Ask":"1.0002","Bid":"0.9998"},{"id":"EURUSD","Name":"EUR/USD","Rate":"1.1443","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"3:08pm","Ask":"1.1443","Bid":"1.1443"},{"id":"EURJPY","Name":"EUR/JPY","Rate":"122.5650","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"4:00pm","Ask":"122.6200","Bid":"122.5100"},{"id":"EURCNY","Name":"EUR/CNY","Rate":"7.4054","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"2:08pm","Ask":"7.4070","Bid":"7.4037"},{"id":"EURGBP","Name":"EUR/GBP","Rate":"0.7836","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"3:22pm","Ask":"0.7837","Bid":"0.7836"},{"id":"EURBRL","Name":"EUR/BRL","Rate":"3.9637","Date":"4/29/2016","Time":"4:28pm","Ask":"3.9679","Bid":"3.9595"}]}}};

//console.log(response.query.results.rate);

var times = response.query.results.rate.map(function(elem){

  if( elem.Time === 'N/A' || elem.Time === 0){
    elem.fullDateTimeStamp = elem.Time;
    //console.log(elem);
    return elem;
  }

  // create full date from the time (using time and date combined)
  // 1) is it AM or PM
  var elemIsPm = (elem.Time.substring(elem.Time.length-2).indexOf("am") == -1);  
  
  // 2) remove AM/PM and get hour:min into array
  var elemArr = elem.Time.substring(0, elem.Time.length-2).split(":");
  
  // 3) add 12 hours if PM and not noon
  if( elemIsPm && elemArr[0] != 12){
    elemArr[0] = parseInt(elemArr[0]) + 12;
  }
  //console.log(elemArr[0]);
  
  // 4) however, if it is 12, we deduct 12 if it's not PM
  if( elemArr[0] == 12 && !elemIsPm ){
    elemArr[0] = elemArr[0] - 12;
  }
    
  // 5) create date object
  var elemDateString = elem.Date;
  var elemDateOnly = new Date(elemDateString);
  //console.log(elemDateOnly);
  
  var elemTS = new Date(elemDateOnly.getFullYear(), elemDateOnly.getMonth(), elemDateOnly.getDate(), elemArr[0], elemArr[1], 0, 0);
  elem.fullDateTimeStamp = elemTS;
  
//  console.log(elem);
  
  // 4) return
  return elem;
});

 console.log( times );


var lastOne = times.reduce(function(prevVal, elem) {  
//  console.log('p');
//  console.log(prevVal );
  
//  console.log('e');
//  console.log(elem );
  
  if( prevVal === 'N/A' || prevVal === 0 || prevVal.Time){
    return elem;
  }
  
  //console.log(prevVal.fullDateTimeStamp);
      
  return (prevVal.fullDateTimeStamp < elem.fullDateTimeStamp)? elem : prevVal;
  
}, 0);

document.getElementById('latest').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(lastOne);

console.log('====> ');

console.log( JSON.stringify(lastOne.fullDateTimeStamp) );
```

```html
Last date:
<div id='latest'></div>
```

Comment: ty for your answer, it will help me a lot, but what i want is not get the most recent of these 12 query results. What I want is, always get the latest results of each query. [link](http://mib.com.br/testes/cambio/cambio.html) here's my code, refresh this page and look at the results, they change when refresh the page.

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior ok, let me see what I can do - I will be busy for the next few hours, check back later this afternoon

Comment: Ty man, i got it, u help me so much, ty for all :P and sorry for anything.

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior hey, no worries... (nothing to be sorry about) - I am glad I could help

Comment: haha I need 15 reputation points to upvote :P but, when i got it, I'll back and up-vote your answer